# Given that there are 6 married couples. If we select only 4 people out of 12, what is the probability that none of them are married to each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Please, can you help me to solve this?
Given that there are 6 married couples. If we select only 4 people out of 12, what is the probability that none of them are married to each other?

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We want to count the number of ways that we can choose $4$ people from the $12$ so that no two are married to each other. But then each person must belong to a different couple. So first, we choose the $4$ special couples from the $6$. Then for each couple, we choose $1$ of the $2$ partners. This yields:
$$
\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}^4
$$

Comment: And this must be divided to total outcomes ?

Comment: Another way to think about this same number is that you can choose 12 people at first, but then every time you choose *one* person, you remove *two* from the pool, so you end up with $12\cdot 10\cdot 8\cdot 6$. But this is just ${6\choose 4} \cdot 2^4$.

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan Yes, you'd have to divide by the total number to get the probability.